# What causes my Gazebo robot model to repeatedly give "Couldn't find an AF_INET address for []" in termiinal and crash

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am changing a world file to a model and removed the world content and only have the model.

I'm new to gazebo and do not know why this is happening

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/13736/what-causes-my-gazebo-robot-model-to-repeatedly-give-%22couldn%27t-find-an-af_inet-address-for-%5B%5D%22-in-termiinal-and-crash/) by [Blui](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2681/blui/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 5 on 2016-06-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You're probably using a model with ROS plugins. I've noticed this when I use robot models that use the gazebo_ros_control plugin and possibly others. Are you using ROS? If you comment out all the plugins in your robot it should go away.

---

Originally posted by [Peter Mitrano](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1068/peter-mitrano/) with karma: 768 on 2016-06-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Blui](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2681/blui/) on 2016-06-29**:
Thank you this solved it!

**Comment by [Peter Mitrano](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1068/peter-mitrano/) on 2016-06-29**:
Glad to hear it -- please accept the answer so everyone knows this is resolved.